# Insert text at caret of input text in Ionic2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to create simple calculator app.

I want to insert text at caret of input text on tapping(clicking) button.
The following code does not work at `strPos = inputText.selectionStart;`.
Seems no error occurs, just stop here.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**Edit**

page1.html

```
<ion-input #myInput type="text" [value]="fomula" (focus)="onFocus($event)"></ion-input>
<button class="button" id="number" (click)="numberTapped(myInput, 1)">1</button>
```

page1.ts

```
onFocus($event){
  this.currentInput = document.activeElement;
}

numberTapped($event, number) {
  this.insertAtCaret($event, String(number))
}

insertAtCaret(inputId,text) {
  var inputText:any = myInput; //document.getElementById(inputId);
  var strPos = 0;
  strPos = inputText.selectionStart;

  var front = (inputText.value).substring(0,strPos);  
  var back = (inputText.value).substring(strPos,inputText.value.length); 
  inputText.value=front+text+back;
  strPos = strPos + text.length;
  inputText.selectionStart = strPos;
  inputText.selectionEnd = strPos;
  inputText.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when `numberTapped` is called, the focus is already lost and onFocus was called again. so at the time when `numberTapped` is executed, `this.currentInput` is not the input anymore.

even if i think your approach is not the best, a solution might be

```
<ion-input #myinput type="text" [value]="fomula" (focus)="onFocus($event)"></ion-input>
<button class="button" id="number" (click)="numberTapped(myinput, 1)">1</button>
```

doing so, `#myinput` is now a reference to the element.

#### from the docs [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

```
<!-- phone refers to the input element; pass its `value` to an event handler -->
<input #phone placeholder="phone number">
<button (click)="callPhone(phone.value)">Call</button>

<!-- fax refers to the input element; pass its `value` to an event handler -->
<input ref-fax placeholder="fax number">
<button (click)="callFax(fax.value)">Fax</button>
```

> The hash (#) prefix to "phone" means that we're defining a phone variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both `(click)="numberTapped(myinput, 1)"` and `(click)="insertAtCaret(myinput, 1)"` but didn't work for me. The program stops at `strPos = inputText.selectionStart;`.

Comment: have you chaned also `insertAtCaret` accordingly to use myinput instead?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Please check my edited code. I appreciate if you give me any suggestions.

Comment: im sorry, i believe i cannot help you as you seem to not understand the basics. e.g. you still have the inputId arg defined, while using myInput, which is not defined in the context. that are basics i have no time to explain...

Answer (score 0):

**I Use This In My Ionic 4 Project**

```
<ion-input #ioninput clear-input="true" placeholder="Text ..."> </ion-input>
<ion-button ion-button block (click)="insertAtCursor('value')">Button</ion-button>
```

**Am Using Angular 8 | ViewChild In Angular 8 Need 2 Arguments**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonInput } from '@ionic/angular';
export class TextPage implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('ioninput', {static: false}) ioninputRef: IonInput;
constructor(){}
 insertAtCursor(textToInsert) {
// make sure we have focus in the right input
this.ioninputRef.setFocus();
// and just run the command
document.execCommand('insertText', false /*no UI*/, textToInsert);
     }
}
```

**Hope This will help someone :)**